# Sending the type to a function and reading a specific data type

Tags: c

**First question:** Can I send the type to a function?
Example if I write a generic function that works for any type.

**And the second question:**
I want to write a function to make sure that I read one of the following data types: **int, float, double, long long**.

Here's how I want it to work if I read an int:

1. If I enter "abcd" the function will print a message asking to enter  a valid int number.
2. If I enter "123abc"  the function will print a message asking to enter  a valid int number.

The only valid cases are :

1. If I enter "123"
   or
2. If I enter "123 456" in this case the function will read only the first number letting the second one in buffer.

Here is my code for this function:

```
int citesteNumar(char mesaj[])
{
    char c;
    int nr=0;
    int semn = 1;
    int cifre = 0;
    bool ok = false;
    while(1)
    {
        nr = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            c = getchar();
            if(c == ' ' && !ok)
                continue;
            if((((c < '0') || ('9' < c)) && (c != '-')) || (c == '\n'))
            {
                if(c != ' ')
                    fflush(stdin);
                if((c != '\n') && (c != ' ') && ok)
                    ok = false;
                break;
            }
            else if(c == '-')
                 {
                     if(!ok)
                        semn = -1;
                     else
                     {
                         fflush(stdin);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                else
                {
                    nr = nr*10 + (c - '0');
                    ok = true;
                    cifre ++;
                    if(cifre == 10)
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(!ok)
            printf("%s",mesaj);
        else return semn*nr;
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Can I write a generic function to read this types: **int, float, double, long long** ?

The first invalid case it can be solved using the value returned by `scanf` function but I don't know how to solve the second case (only with the method above).

And the function needs to be portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PROC(type) \
    if(*endp){\
        printf("enter a valid " #type " number.\n");\
        return NULL;\
    }\
    if(ret = malloc(sizeof(v)))\
        *(type*)ret = v;\
    /**/

void *GetNumber(const char *type){
    void *ret = NULL;
    char temp[32], *endp;
    scanf("%31s", temp);
    if(strcmp("int", type)==0){
        int v = strtol(temp, &endp, 10);
        PROC(int)
    } else if(strcmp("long long", type)==0){
        long long v = strtoll(temp, &endp, 10);
        PROC(long long)
    } else if(strcmp("float", type)==0){
        float v = strtod(temp, &endp);
        PROC(float)
    } else if(strcmp("double", type)==0){
        double v = strtod(temp, &endp);
        PROC(double)
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    int *vi;
    float *vf;
    while((vi = GetNumber("int")) == NULL)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", *vi);
    free(vi);
    if(vf = GetNumber("float"))
        printf("%f\n", *vf);
    free(vf);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't send the type, but you can send an `enum` :

```
typedef enum {
  MY_NONE,
  MY_INT,
  MY_FLOAT,
  MY_DOUBLE,
  MY_LL
} Mytype;
```

In your function, use a switch on the `enum`. Plus, use `sscanf` on your buffer, with the corresponding format. You will get troubles to read an `int` with a blank inside; perhaps look at the locale, you might find solutions.

Comment: `sscanf` still not solve the second case in witch if I enter a char next to a number is an invalid case.